# Google Cloud DataFlow Deployment Failed

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to deploy GCP flex-template DataFlow via terraform(Resource Creation). I did below steps:

1. Created Docker image and pushed to container registry. Docker file
   has below code:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Configure access to GCP
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=creds_key.json
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=creds_key.json


RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install poetry==1.2.1
RUN poetry self add "keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth=^1" -v
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install -v
#RUN rm -rf cred_key.json
# Entry Point for Dataflow Job:
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="./run_pipeline.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE="./setup.py"
```

Service Account used to deploy the resource has access to below roles, and above key file is also same.

```
dataflow worker
storage admin
storage object admin
storage object creator
Service Account User/Actor
Pub/Sub Admin/Subscriber
```

Error:

```
Response: {"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."}
```

I got the different error when i removed auth activate-service-account:

I can see that the file `creds_key.json` is available in image.

Comment: Have you included name of service account with the command `gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT-NAME --key-file=KEY_FILE`? Also can you make sure you have given the correct location of the key file.You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#authorize_with_a_service_account) for more information.

Comment: Hi @SunithaM, Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes @PrajnaRaiT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be solved by including name of service account with the command:

`gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT-NAME --key-file=KEY_FILE`

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#authorize_with_a_service_account).